# grub takes minutes to load

Tags: 11.10, grub2

After BIOS, grub's background image is shown. then I'll have to wait more than a minute for grub's boot menu to appear.

After the menu is shown, everything behaves normally. I'm running Oneiric.

Anything wrong with my [config file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/749152/) or any other ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with GRUB and not with the BIOS? Have you got any sign that it's actually GRUB to hang?

Comment: as the background image of grub is shown it seems that BIOS is no longer in control. i suggest to try it without background image and check whether this causes the issue. but i do not really have a clue what could be causing this. Do you have any USB devices connected, like a smart phone? I once had such an issue with a PC not booting correctly when my HTC Wallaby was connected many years ago.

Comment: i have the same issue, will post an answer here if i find one

Answer (score 1):

your config file look ok. Did you try to reinstall grub? I think it may be your bios looking for plug n play device which either not exist or faulty. anyway you can always reinstall grub from within your ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I disconnected all the external usb devices, manually deactivated the background image, used grub-mkconfig and update-grub. I should tell you that the behaviour changed recently: First, the menu is shown and the selection of the first menu entry leads to the long waiting. This is with and without background image. That lead me to the question if there's something wrong with the kernel.

I think that's it [dmesg](http://paste.ubuntu.com/750138/): Due to kernel problems I don't yet understand, My hdd is started really late and so it seemed like grub froze.

So, the problem changed from grub to kernel. Let's see what the seardh machines say to this.

Answer (score 0):

Waaaah! Got it! The kernel hat problems with my DVD-ROM! My solution: Adding libata.force=2:pio4 to the kernel command line. [Here you'll find more details.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1549579m)

Comment: See [Launchpad Bug # 445852](https://bugs.launchpad.net/libatasmart/+bug/445852)